# Computing homology of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to calculate homology groups of a a torus using Meyer-Vietoris sequence. Let $A,B$ be a half of a torus homeomorphic to $S^{1} \times I $. Let's enlarge them so that they intersect and $A \cup B=T$, $A \cap B=S^1 \cup S^1$.
Then for $i>1$
$$H_{i}(A \cap B)=0,H_{i}(A)=H_{i}(B)=0$$
Hence the nontrivial sequence looks like this:
$$0 \rightarrow H_2(T) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H_{1}(T) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) [H_0(A \cap B)]\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})[H_0(A) \times H_0(B)] \rightarrow H_0(T) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 $$

$ \delta\colon H_0(A) \times H_0(B) \rightarrow H_0(T)$
is epimorphic hence $\ker(\delta) = \mathbb{Z}$. And analogously $\ker(\delta_2) =\mathbb{Z}$
where $$\delta_2\colon H_0(A \cap B)\rightarrow H_0(A) \times H_0(B)$$
And unfortunately that's all I can get out of this. How can I show that $H_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?
Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: You're going to need to look a little more closely at how each of the maps in the sequence is defined. Go back to your notes and check exactly how each group maps to the next.